# FirstOrDefault returns null on foreign key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Lets say we have the following model :

```
public class ReadingOrder
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
Table("db_ReadingOrder");
Id(o => o.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
References(o => o.Order, "OrderId");
```

I want to get the `ReadingOrder` which has the `orderId` equal with 1 (eg).
But when I try a `FirstOrDefault`, the query returns null :

```
var readingO = _repositoryFactory.GetRepository<ReadingOrder>().FirstOrDefault(xz => xz.Order.Id == 1);
```

If I get all of them and after apply a `FirstOrDefault` works, but its stupid:

```
var readingOrderList1 = _repositoryFactory.GetRepository<ReadingOrder>()
                         .GetAll().FirstOrDefault(xz => xz.Order.Id == 1);
```

The method from repository has the following format:

```
public T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
   return _session.Query<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

easy stuff, but not working. If I go for a normal property, like `Id`, all works as expected.
Also, if I get the generated query from log and put it in sqlite, it runs successfully and the reading order is returned. Is there a bug in NHibernate? Is a mapping problem? Or is it a problem with SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I found the problem : the name of the foreign key column **"OrderId"**.
Nhibernate looks for *"Hibernate.Order"* in this case, I don`d know why, but after I changed the name of the column, the item is now retrieved from db. Thank you all for your answers! I gave the bounty to user *Syed Farjad Zia Zaid*i, because he helped me to isolate the problem. It was clear that was an Nhibernate issue, so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I see you can make this work either change your mapping as:

```
Table("db_ReadingOrder");
Id(o => o.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
References(o => o.Order);
```

and then query:

```
var readingO = _repositoryFactory.GetRepository<ReadingOrder>().FirstOrDefault(xz => xz.Order.Id == 1);
```

Otherwise you can also change your mapping as:

```
Table("db_ReadingOrder");
Id(o => o.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
References(o => o.Order).Column("OrderId");
```

and then query:

```
var readingO = _repositoryFactory.GetRepository<ReadingOrder>().FirstOrDefault(xz => xz.Order.OrderId == 1);
```

Comment: Same result... for this two mappings. But, as an update, it works for all others entities except this.

Comment: if it is working all other entities then try reproducing this problem in a separate project...

Comment: I tried in a separate project...  is no problem with entity framework! its an Nhibernate issue I think

Comment: But it does not make sense. If its working with other entities then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

some times that's related to dynamic global filters, like a soft delete method by a `IsDeleted` prop so u need to fetching ignored items and using some methods like this `.IgnoreQueryFilters()` in ef.

Answer (score -1):

The same scenario works fine with the following code at the repository.

```
      public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(
      Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
      Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
      string includeProperties = "")
    {

            IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }
            if (includeProperties != null)
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                    (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProperty);
                }

            return query.ToList();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify your class like this:

```
public class ReadingOrder
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }    // Explicit and direct foreign Key
}
```

and then retrieve your query using `OrderId`, instead of `Order.Id`:

```
var readingO = _repositoryFactory.GetRepository<ReadingOrder>()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(xz => xz.OrderId == 1);
```